# Javascript polygon selector, polygon brush

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, maps, polygon

I need a 'polygon' selector type functionality. Basically, the ability to drag lines to form multiple polygons; pref with the ability to edit the 'points' of the polygon after the shape has been 'closed' (but that's secondary) and/or move the polygons...

I generally dislike 'reinventing the wheel' and I figured I'd find tons of examples to work with, but I was wrong...

The polygon tool in Google Maps is just about perfect, but has anyone utilized it outside of GMaps? (I recall it required a GMap as an attribute from my work with Google Maps). Before I roll up my sleeves, I just want to ensure there isn't something already made (this is a very small part) - so if (a) Google Maps Polygon object is usable without a map, or (b) there's another library/project I'm missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Fabricjs is an option you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) which has a great api for visualizing data and geo information. Besides the standard one-/two-dimensional brush there are plugins for more advanced types of brushes:

1. [Polybrush](https://gist.github.com/gtb104/3667340). Providing a polygon brush.
2. [lasso](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/lasso). Lassoing a selection by freely drawing a line path.

Comment: Thanks, I actually looked at polybrush and gave editting it a whirl the other day. I got stuck on not being able to create multiple polygons at once (i.e. create a polygon, then go back into brush mode to create another and another on screen)... I think what I need to do there is once a polygon is closed it should create a standalone polygon object, seperate/unreliant on the brush... That way you can create polygon after polygon... 
If I give it another shot, I'll report back.

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli That sounds very similar to the solution I put together just a couple of days ago but using d3's standard brush having rectangular brush extents. However, I did it the same way like you did: right after brushing finished I cleared the brush and drew a rectangle at its extent's position. The tricky part was to keep track of those rectangle because I had the requirement to reattach the brush on mouseover events to be able to adjust it afterwards. I am planning to put this into a working gist, but I haven't had the time yet.